# NSContreteAttributedString:initWithString: crash

Tags: ios, crash, nsattributedstring

I would like to know what's the possible reason?
mAutoCommentLabel.text is nil or cellFont is nil?

```
UIFont* cellFont = mAutoCommentLabel.font;    
NSAttributedString *attrStr = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:mAutoCommentLabel.text attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: cellFont}];

CGRect rect =
[attrStr boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(withWidth, CGFLOAT_MAX)
                             options:(NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin|NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading)
                             context:nil];

int commentHeight = rect.size.height;
```

Crash log from app store heres:
[image]

Comment: Why don't you check "AutoCommentLabel.text is nil or cellFont is nil?"? I think text is nil

Comment: I added just now, but I am not quite sure this will be the root cause of the crash.